# How to silently add a notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I'd like to selectively hide and show a notification based on what a user does.

Since that would happen pretty often, I'd like to have it appear in the notification dropdown without having the text message appear in the status bar every time I show it.

[Task manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rhythm.hexise.task&feature=search_result) does it when I toggle it in its preference screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the `Notification` object, pass `null` for the ticker text.

```
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
```